# how to populate a jtable by selecting a jcombobox value

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I'm new to programming. I have a database with a table appointments. table fields doctors, patient_name. I want to populate a jtable with doctor and patient_name by selecting a doctor from a jcombobox. I tried like below but in table brings only the column name and no data. There is no error. Thanks.

```
   try
{
String comboVal=(String)cbox_doctors.getSelectedItem();
String sql1="select doctor, patient_firstname, patient_surname from 
appointments where doctor=?";
pst1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst1.setString(1, comboVal);
rs1=pst1.executeQuery();

while(rs1.next())
{
table_report.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));

}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");
System.out.println(e);
} finally {

        try{

            rs1.close();
            pst1.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
     }
```

Comment: What error do you encounter? If it's coming as from your `try` block, you should print the error message by adding `System.out.println(e);` to your catch block or by using `e.printStackTrace()` so you can tell what's going on.

Comment: I solved the error , was a typing error. But still not working. in jtable appears only the column name. No data .